# How to undergrade Report viewer 11.0.0.0 to Report viewer 10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I have created a winform project with VS 2013 and I used Report Viewer (automatically on ver 11.0.0.0) for reporting it works fine on almost all windows versions except windows XP SP3; because Report Viewer need clr types for sql server 2012 that dose not install on Win XP.
If i use Report viewer 10.0.0.0 there wont be any problem with installing my app on any client. How can i undergrad from ver 11.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0?
I need to deliver it tomorrow! otherwise i wont get paid!! );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't worked with Report Viewer, but I actually had to do a lot of downgrading for other dlls. In your reference folder in your solution, remove the Report Viewer reference. Afer that, you either download and manually reference the 10.0 dll or you can execute this command in the manager console https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Report.Viewer/10.0.0

Comment: Thank you so for your clear answer. I did it but it throws an exception (The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.)

Comment: Check this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47ecd315-6372-46cf-b319-df098334fc74/the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target-namespace?forum=vsreportcontrols . Basically, you need to replace every reference in the project where you see 11.0.0.0.